# Angular 2 app with Webpack - npm install is not installing correct version dependecies

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, npm-install, package.json

My application is not using angular-cli. Following is the package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "5.0.5",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "XYZ",
  "homepage": "https://google.com",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.13",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap-progressbar": "^0.9.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-flot": "^0.8.3",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-fontawesome": "0.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.29",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.28",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0 ",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^4.5.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "parse5": "^1.5.1",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Now when I try to run `npm install` or `npm install --exact-versions`, it does not install the correct versions of angular dependencies mentioned in packag.json file.

Following is the installed dependencies tree for angular libraries printed after `npm install` or `npm install --exact-versions' command.

```
+-- @angular/animations@4.2.6
| `-- tslib@1.7.1
+-- @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/forms@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.6
+-- @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.2
```

In `package.json`, the version specified for angular related dependencies in ^4.0.0. But as you can see, only `@angular/animations` is installed with version 4.2.6. Other angular dependencies are installed with version 2.0.0-rd.6 and router is installed with version 3.0.0-rc.2.

Please suggest if I am missing anything in `package.json` file. My `npm` version in **3.10.10** and `node` version is **6.11.0**

Comment: What versions are mentioned when you do 'npm ls'?

Comment: Delete node_modules folder inside the project, and then run command 'npm install'